# Se repiten los likes con el ngFor y quiero que se asignen de forma individual

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**TS:** Según si like está en true o en false, el corazón aparece con relleno o vacío.

```js
async giveLike() {
    if (this.heartType == 'heart-outline' || !this.like) {
        this.heartType = 'heart';
        this.like = true;
        const userId = await this.auth.getUid();
        let user: User = {
            username: '',
            userId,
            correo: '',
            imagenesPerfil: [],
            rol: null,
            telefono: '',
            descripcion: '',
            like: this.like,
            sueldo: null,
            ubicacion: null,
        };
        const data: Like = {
            userId,
            user,
            fecha: new Date(),
            like: this.like,
            imagen: '',
        };
        this.firestoreService.createDoc(data, 'Perfiles/'+userId+'likes/', userId);
        this.firestoreService.createDoc(user, 'Perfiles/', userId);
    } else {
        this.heartType = 'heart-outline';
        this.like = false;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**
Tengo un ngFor para conseguir mostrar los usuarios y poderlos buscar mediante un ion-searchbar y quiero que, además de que se reproduzcan todos los corazones en cada uno de los usuarios. Mi objetivo es conseguir que se pueda dar like a un solo usuario.

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios; let user of searchedUser" lines="none">
    <ion-label> Nombre: {{usuario.username}} </ion-label>
    <img src="{{usuario.imagenes}}" alt="Imagen">
    <ion-buttons>
        <ion-tab-button (click)="giveLike()">
            <!--<ion-icon [name]='heartType'></ion-icon>-->
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!like" name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="like" name="heart"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button> 
    </ion-buttons>       
</ion-item>
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentas conseguir con `*ngFor="let usuario of usuarios; let user of searchedUser"`? No creo que funcione intentar recorrer dos arrays a la vez así

Comment: Son dos arrays, el primero recorre todos los usuarios que existen en la base de datos, y el segundo mediante una función consigo que pueda buscar los usuarios que quiero con una barra de busqueda

Comment: Lo correcto para este caso es identificar el `usuario` al llamar `giveLike()`, por ejemplo: `giveLike(usuario.id)` por lo que en la función se debe recibir el parámetro de ID de usuario y con este realizar la acción hacia el servidor y con la respuesta actualizar el usuarios con la propiedad `like` en `true`, así por data binding se actualizaría la vista.

Comment: ¿Podrías escribirlo en código por favor? Estoy intentando ponerlo con el usuario.userId y no me funciona.